# Where/how can I whitelist access to my Google Apps API?

Tags: google-admin-settings-api

In the https://developers.google.com/console/help/ page there are instructions for "Whitelisting by IP Address (Server-side applications)".  The directions say to click "Configure traffic filters" on the Quotas page yet that link/button doesn't exist in my view. The only options I see is to Set per-user limits and to request a higher API limit.

Are the instructions out of date or am I not seeing something that's right in front of me?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. The help page is at least almost a year out of date.

> I think the solution is to edit the Allowed Referers list on the API Access pane.

Source:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-ajax-search-api/-/txNfHpKxFiMJ